# javascript jsTree "check_node" loop taking 30+ seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Ok...i have tried everything i can...each iteration of the loop only has 100 items in the array after im dong the slice of the main array which is 400...why would it take 30 secs each time i hit `sortChunker`...for a total of 2 minutes for this code to run

Mind you my tree has a total of 2000 nodes it has to traverse through...but does jsTree really take that long???

here is my code...

```
var $myTree= $("#myTree");
            var cLength= 100;
            var arrLen= strArry.length;
            var lc= arrLen/ cLength;

          //put data in chunks...
          var myChunker = function(myArrChunk){
              //var start = new Date();
          setTimeout(
               function(){
                   var start = new Date();
                   myArrChunk,  function(key, item){
                    $myTree.jstree("check_node", "#"+item);

                });
                 var end = new Date();


           }, 0);
        }; 
          for(var j = 0; j < lc; j+=1){
                var arrChunk= sArry.slice(i*cLength, (i*cLength) + cLength);

                myChunker (arrChunk);
          }
```

Comment: it really depends, although it is a bit unusual.

Comment: the alert on my `.each` each say 30+ seconds.....

Comment: Well, the more nodes a document has in general, the longer it takes to perform any DOM manipulation. 2000 items is quite a lot of data in my opinion, considering that every of these is probably represented in the DOM by a moderately complex elements aggregation. It could definitely be faster if jsTree would support some sort of batched operations where the plugin would remove the parent of all targetted elements to allowing performing manipulations without causing multiple reflows. However if no such feature exists, you could potentially lazy-load the nodes?

Comment: @plalx How do you lazy load nodes?????

Comment: @DocHoliday Perhaps you could take a look at this plugin http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

Comment: dom manipulation is expensive.  It's usually better to build out a string or the nodes separately, then insert them.  Doing them one at a time is going to slow down your code, a lot.